# JQuery / Javascript convert date from format "yyyy-mm-dd" to readable string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date

I am using an input field to get a date which is stored in a ISO format like "yyyy-mm-dd".

I want to convert it to a human-readable format to display in the HTML, so `2000-05-03` will look something like `May 3, 2000`.

How can I transform it from ISO format to American format?

Comment: There are many, many questions with good answers on [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+parse+date+string) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+format+date) dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [toLocateDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) for it. And with the options format the date.

For your example it will be like this:

```
const date = new Date("2000-05-03");
date.toLocaleString('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' })
console.log(date);
```

Will print **May 3, 2000**

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work lie this: date_string = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' })

Comment: For anyone with a negative offset, the above returns a date for 2 May, not 3 May. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using the below code:

```js
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
var today  = new Date();

console.log(today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options));
```

Check here for more info - [Another Date format related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)